# Plot different colors

Tags: matlab, plot

Let's say `W = [1 3 5; 2 1 5; 6 9 1]` and `K = [0.2, 0.5, 0.3]` How can I plot all elements in k with the same color exept those elements that have **at least one element** in `W` grather than 6? I need that `K(3)`will be plotted with another color respect `K(1)` and `K(2)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to plot as two series. You can use the any/all functions to check the logical condition columnwise: since you want to check rowwise, we need to use the transpose of W.

```
exceptions = find(any(W' > 6));
normals = find(all(W' <= 6));
plot(exceptions, K(exceptions), 'b.')
hold on
plot(normals, K(normals), 'g.')
```

Answer (score 0):

If you plot point-by-point you can change the color correspondingly, for example something like this:

```
for i = 1:size(W,2)
    if find(W>6)~=0
        plot(i,K(i),'xb');hold on
    else
        plot(i,K(i),'xr');hold on
    end
end
```

Since the information you gave is not enough, the code above needs to be modified according to W and K,....

Comment: You should avoid using 'i' as a variable name in Matlab: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14790740/using-i-and-j-as-variables-in-matlab

Comment: @Max you are right, but for me it is an old habit that I am used to ;)